# ACTION_MOVE not reporting correct Y values

Tags: java, android, view, keyboard, touch

I have a keyboard view and I need to track `ACTION_MOVE` when the finger goes out of the keyboard view. Problem is, once it goes outside it stops reporting the correct `Y` value and keeps reporting the last `Y` value when my finger was over the keyboard view.

For debugging I only added a simple `onTouchListener` so I know the rest of the service is not interfering in any way with the touch event.

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.v("YBugDebug", "getRawY() = "+ event.getRawY()+"");
            return true;
        }
});
```

I've been debugging this for days and can't find out why. Any suggestions? I tried `getY()` `getRawY()`, attaching the listener to the root view.

The odd thing is, the `Y` value is reported correctly in Gingerbread and when my ICS device is in landscape. As stated below, the view doesn't seem to respond to hover events.

I tried adding the `onTouch` to the root view, but the results were exactly the same. It's really ming boggling why it can detect a move but not its correct `Y` axis.

Here is how the problem looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this area but are you saying that the ACTION_MOVE event is fired outside the bounds of your KeyboardView?

Comment: Indeed. The touch event starts in bounds of the view, of course, then I move my finger out of bounds. Is this the default behaviour? I tried a simple project where I added a TextView and it reported correct Y values independant of where my figer was.

Comment: See if you can detect the finger going out of bounds with [ACTION_HOVER_EXIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#onHoverEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)), at that point you could basically neglect what ever the values you're getting.

Comment: I overrode the onHoverEvent method to output a message whenever its called, but it seems the method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get a touch even on all of the screen is to wrap your entire content with a frameLayout , and use setOnTouchListener on it , while returning false for its onTouch() method.

I'm pretty sure i've read about an similar alternative way to do it , but i can't remember what it was. Maybe using the view that you already have automatically . Maybe findViewById( R.id.content) or getRootView() , but i'm not sure about them.

Comment: I tried to attach an onTouch listener to the RootView from getRootView(), but the results were the same I get ACTION_MOVE, but the Y coord is bad. I will try the frameLayout thing, but im not sure how will it act with the recieving app, if it wont block input to it.

Comment: if you return false, it shouldn't block anything behind it. I'm pretty sure there is a solution without creating a frameLayout. i can't find what it was that i've found.

Comment: btw, you've shown in the screenshot an example of how to capture the coordinates on the screen via another app . you can use its code instead of what i've written. it's from the dev tools , and should be open source as far as i know.